# What is the difference between AzureMonitorTraceExporter and AzureMonitorSpanExporter?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, open-telemetry, azure-monitor

```
from azure.core.settings import settings
from azure.core.tracing.ext.opentelemetry_span import OpenTelemetrySpan
settings.tracing_implementation = OpenTelemetrySpan

from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchSpanProcessor
```

I was trying to apply opentelemetry to monitor a Azure Function App. And I found there are two ways to configure export: AzureMonitorTraceExporter and AzureMonitorSpanExporter.
What is the difference between them?

```
from  azure.monitor.opentelemetry.exporter  import  AzureMonitorTraceExporter
app_insights_key = os.getenv('APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY_String')
exporter = AzureMonitorTraceExporter.from_connection_string(app_insights_key)
```

and

```
from azure_monitor import AzureMonitorSpanExporter
app_insights_key = os.getenv('APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY')
exporter = AzureMonitorSpanExporter(instrumentation_key=app_insights_key)
```

And which way is better for a Azure Function App? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AzureMonitorSpanExporter` is old one and not supported/developed now. It is moved from  https://github.com/microsoft/opentelemetry-azure-monitor-python to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python. You should be using `AzureMonitorTraceExporter`.

Comment: No wonder I got error when used AzureMonitorSpanExporter. But the AzureMonitorTraceExporter works fine for me. Thank you!